# TNSNames.ora doesn't appear when setting up a oracle odbc driver connection

Tags: oracle, odbc, driver

I want to connect an ASP application with my Oracle database, and i've readed  that I have to set up a connection with my Oracle DB with ODBC driver to achieve it.

The problem is, that when I create the new ODBC connection, it asks for the TNSNames, and my the connection that I have in my TNSNames.ora doesn't appear in the drop list (it appears empty).

Im trying to create the connection going to the ODBC configuration in Control Panel.

Someone has any idea on how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Khor

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved it.

What worked was creating a windows enviroment variable called TNS_ADMIN with the path to my admin folder on the oracle directory.

TNS_ADMIN: "C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\network\admin"

That solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the example - I'd set `TNS_ADMIN` to the path and filename of `tnsnames.ora` but I should have only put in the path, without the `tnsnames.ora` on the end!

Answer (score 0):

You probably use Win64.

If yes then you must configure ODBC DSN in the same Windows subsystem as Oracle. Check if you installed Oracle client in 32 or 64 bit version.

There are 2 version of `odbcad32.exe` in 64 bit versions of Windows. In `c:\windows\system32` you will find 64 bit that configure ODBC for 64 bit applications and will use setting from 64 bit version of Oracle client. In `c:\windows\syswow64` there is 32 bit version you should use to configure ODBC for 32 bit programs including 32 bit version of Oracle client.